# I want to retrieve data from a sevlet but nothing is showing

Tags: java, jsp, ejb

I'm new to EJB (NetBeans), I have got entities class, session bean with remote interface. However, I'm using a sevlet but my data is not appearing on my jsp page. (Can somebody show me how not to use a sevlet **optional**)

This is my SessionBean

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "EnterpriseGreenAgency-ejbPU")
private EntityManager em;    
@Override
public List<Property> getProperty() 
 List<Property> listP = em.createQuery("SELECT P FROM Property  p").getResultList();
    return listP;
```

this is my remote interface

```
@Remote
public interface EstateLogiBeanRemote {

    public List getProperty();    
}
```

This is my sevelt

```
@EJB
   private EstateLogiBeanRemote estateLogiBean;


  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    List<Property> propertyList = estateLogiBean.getProperty();
        request.setAttribute("pL", propertyList);

  }
```

This is my JSP page

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="pL">
        <p><c:out value="${p.getPropertyId()}"></c:out></p>
        <p><c:out value="${p.getPropertyId()}"></c:out></p>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Quick guess: your doGet() does nothing, you are missing a forward to the JSP

Comment: Thank you Idan for reply how do I forward it pls

Comment: Thank you Gyro Gearless  for reply how do I forward it pls

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not referencing the pL object correctly in your JSTL loop.
you have:

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="pL">
```

it should be:

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="${pL}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chris Thompson.  I would also add that em.createQuery("SELECT P FROM Property  p"), I believe is case-sensitive, so rewrite em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Property  p").